# How to prepare mediaplayer in android while another playing?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I using MediaPlayerto play video from http stream is any solution to prepare second media player with another http url while first one still playing? 
I want to play two videos without black screen between them, when first one end second start immediately.

Here is my code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView playerSurfaceView;
private String videoSrc  = "http://192.168.1.101:8090/api/video/";
private String android_id;

private MediaPlayer next;
private static boolean firstCall = true;
private String secondVideoSrc = "http://192.168.1.101:8090/api/secondvideo/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    playerSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.playersurface);
    surfaceHolder = playerSurfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    GetDeviceId();
    videoSrc += android_id;
    secondVideoSrc += android_id;
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    prepareVideoPlayer();

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

private void GetDeviceId() {
    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}



private void prepareVideoPlayer() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(videoSrc));
        mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(firstCall) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    firstCall = false;
                }
                new AsyncPrepareNext().execute();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                next.start();
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
private void prepareNext() {
    try {
        next = new MediaPlayer();
        next.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        next.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(secondVideoSrc));
        next.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        next.prepareAsync();
        next.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
        next.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        next.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
private class AsyncPrepareNext extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        prepareNext();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

When i run this first video starts for 2 or 3 seconds and then stop with some errors like media server died, audio flinger died, error (100,0), error (38,0)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to implement the OnPreparedListener() and OnCompletedListener() to accomplish this and you might need 2 media players for it as well.

```
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
        // Set Video Source for second video
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        // Prepare second video
        mp.prepareAsync();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        // Start second video here
        mp.start();
    }
```

and set them like this:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener());
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletedListener(new OnCompletionListener());
```

Comment: I already use two media players and already implement onPrepared onCompleted as u can see in my code.... when i call prepareAsync or prepare video stop and i got  errors media server die error (100, 0)

Comment: What device are you running this on? It's possible that the device doesn't support multiple videos at once. Also, have you tried using the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)? In encapsulates a lot of this stuff for you, then all you have to worry about is switching views.

Comment: You could also try implementing an onErrorLIstener to try and narrow down what the error is. Are both the video formats in the supported by the device? Try playing them individually through the default player app to see if you still get errors.

Comment: device not problem... probably is HTTP connection because i need two parallel connections for two videos... video is not problem when i call prepare for second media player in oncompletedListener of first evrething works fine but have black screen for a 3-5 seconds while preparing video.

Comment: Unless you store the videos on the device locally, I dont think you're going to be able to remove that black screen. Newer Android devices, although powerful, are still limited in how much memory they have. 3-5 seconds is not that bad for a video stream over a network. The default MediaPlayer in Android is also pretty basic. If you want better results you can always try another media player like [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)